# What are the benefits of using mail distribution services?

Tags: email, mailing-lists

I want to setup a small mailing list (about 100 emails) and send mails about 1 time per 1-2 weeks. Why would I want to use a professional service for this, such as MailChimp or Mad Mimi, instead of just using Outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Using mail service (MailChimp, Mad Mimi, etc.):

  - They will handle tracking which addresses could not be delivered to and can provide tracking which users read the mails/clicked links via some redirector (to the extent users don't defend against this).
  - You don't have to install and set up anything special.
  - It ensures you don't leak the addresses in the headers.
- Using mailing list software (majordomo, mailman, ezmlm and such):

  - It allows people to subscribe/unsubscribe themselves and can handle undeliverable addresses, but it does not handle tracking.
  - It allows whoever you want to allow to send email to the list.
  - It does not leak the addresses in the headers.
  - Disadvantage is that you have to install it.
- Using outlook:

  - You have to exclude failed addresses yourself, manually.
  - You have to make sure you use the addresses in *Bcc*, not To. Writing the addresses in To is a privacy issue and huge faux pas.
  - It is more complicated to get the distribution list from some other system, e.g. CRM database.

Each of the methods will easily handle the load. Depends on what extra features you want.